# mingw winsock2.h and ws2tcpip.h

Tags: sockets, window, mingw, bitcoin

```
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/ws2tcpip.h:38:2: error
: #error "ws2tcpip.h is not compatible with winsock.h. Include winsock2.h instea
d."
```

I been trying to compile an alt coin that is of keccak sha 3 algorithm, but I keep get this error when trying to compile, it say ws2tcpip.h is not compatible with winsock.h , been trying for the past 2-3 days, but still not able get past this.

Got once I tried to replace ws2tcpip.h file with winsock2.h content, end up I get an error at netbase.cpp where it require the header of ws2tcpip.h on getaddrinfo

Hope someone can help on how to resolve this. I trying to fork max coin . Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

windows.h includes winsock.h so you'll need to put the ws2tcpip.h include before any windows.h include.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to danron's answer you can include `winsock2.h` in any order as long as `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined